# why does fork() return all possible outputs in this combination?

Tags: c, output, fork, child-process

**Question:**

I need clarification/help on my understanding of fork() outputs. I know how to program more detailed and larger code in c with fork() and use other concepts like pipe, ipc, threads(posix). But my understanding with predicting return output is bad which is why I'm trying to figure this out I believe my case 1 is correct but my other cases are ambiguous or similar to that because i'm not quite solid with output of fork().

My knowledge with program output is decent, I understand basic algorithms that contain for-loop, while-loop, if/else, data structures, recursive outputs.

However, **I am lacking knowledge on how programs using fork() exactly outputs and how parent/child processes combinations are exactly as stated below**.

**My Approach:**

Originally we have a parent process running p0 then pid forks a child process.

So, all possible outputs will always contain 0 because num=0 initially and before the first prinf() statement num is not set to any other number.

I believe the timing for parent and child process execution is random because it can come out in any order.

case 1: p0 prints 02 because there can be a case where pid is a parent. Then the forked child process p1 prints 01. Final answer would be 0201

case 2: p0 prints 01 because there can be a case where pid is a child (is it a child of the main process from kernel? ). Then the forked child p1 is a parent so it prints 0102. Final answer would be 0102

case 3: p0 prints 00 since pid is not a child or parent. Then the forked child p1 prints 12 because it is a child and a parent at the same time. Final answer would be 0012.

case 4: p0 prints 00 since it is not a parent or child. Then the forked child process p1 prints 21 because it can be a parent and a child at the same time.
Final answer would be 0021.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int num = 0 ;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int pid ;
  pid = fork() ;

  printf("%d",num) ;

  if (pid == 0) {
    num = 1;
  } else if (pid > 0) {
    num = 2 ;
  }
  printf("%d",num) ;
}
```

Answer: 0102 or 0012 or 0201 or 0021

Comment: You have no control over when each of the two processes will run or in which order. If you want the processes work in a specific order, you have to use some sort of interprocess synchronization.

Comment: the parent and child are racing on that `printf` to `stdout`. There isn't much else to it.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm trying to understand is how does one find the pattern of all possible outputs because that is what im not understanding because I can randomly print numbers like 0120 but it isn't included in the 'answers'.

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). It has several chapters explaining `fork` and how to use it and when.

Comment: C is, disregarding loops and such, pretty much sequential. Statements are performed from top to bottom, in the order you have programmed it. So if the code should print the number `0` before either `1` or `2`, then the number `0` will *never* be printed after you print either `1` or `2`. That means the case `0120` is *impossible* to get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are overcomplicating it. What happens after a `fork()`, is that you have two instances (father and son) executing, each of them performing two output operations.

The two instances are independent and don't know anything about each other, so one will not wait for the other to complete and you have a so-called *race condition*. The only guarantee is that each process will output first `0`, then `1` (or `2`), because that's the order of operations in each of them. But you can't say how the four output operations will be interleaved.

Comment: would 0120 be a possible output?

Comment: No, because you must retain the correct order for each instance: first `0`, then `1` or `2`. `0120` could have been `01` and `20` or `02` and `10`, and both do not respect that.

Comment: When you say the first  outputs must be 0 and then 1 or 2. Does that mean position 0 is 0 then position 1  is  1 or 2? Because what if position 1 is 0 does that mean fork() failed?

Comment: No, `0012` is ok. Imagine the two instances are running in separate windows: one will output `01` and the other `02`. Right? Now try to interleave the two outputs: `0102`, `0012` are ok, but `0120` is not, because there is no `0` following a `1` or `2` or `0` in the separate outputs.

Comment: I'm starting to understand that a parent process will always print 02 and child process will always print 01 so the combinations of output really comes from interleaving basically?

Comment: Yes, exactly. What's more, if you printed more than one character per `printf`, the outputs could be even interleaved at a character level, so if one process printed `HELLO WORLD` and the other `foo bar baz`, you could get `HELfoo  LObarW bazORLD` as output, as long as the order of the two independent outputs is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the parent process A, and the child B.  A is always going to print a `0` followed by a `2`. B is always going to print a `0` followed by a `1`. The timing of A with respect to B is undefined. The output from A could print before, interleaved, or after the output from B.

There are actually six possible outcomes as shown below. However, you'll only see four different output patterns, because you can't tell whether A or B printed first, when the output starts with `00`.

```
AABB
0201

ABAB
0021

BAAB
0021

ABBA
0012

BABA
0012

BBAA
0102
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thanks for clearing it up. From my understand I will try to study this and understand more so I may respond later because I  just now understood that it basically depends on interleaving and time

Comment: I will review this output you displayed and if I have questions I will leave comments

Comment: So when AA or BB is occurring in the pattern that means there are no faults or interleaving but when AB, BA occurs that means there is a fault/error and interleaving occurs?

Comment: @geforce The A and B processes run independently, but share a single output device. On a multicore processor, A and B will run simultaneously and will race to generate output. If A wins, you'll see AABB. If B wins then BBAA. Sometimes the timing is so close that the outputs interleave, and you get something like ABAB. On a single core processor, the operating system will switch between A and B at regular intervals. So A might output a 0, and the OS switches to B which outputs 0 1, and then the OS switches back to A, resulting in ABBA. No faults/errors are involved, it's just multitasking.